# Add a check in the components helper that checks for the running user's profile

Tags: lightning-aura-components, aura, lightning-components

I have the following function in my js helper class. I just need to view the labels on basis of user's profile. If Profile name is 'ABC' then show Label L1,L2 and L3. And IF profile is 'xyz' show labels L4,L5.

Please help me with the syntax and code for fetching Profileid / profile name of the user and where should I include that condition. Any help is much appriciated. Thanks.

```js
getRecordType : function(component, recId) {
        var help = this;
        this.sendRequest(component, 'c.getRecordType', {'recId' : recId})
        .then($A.getCallback(function(recordType) {
            var options = [];
            console.log(recordType);
            if(recordType == 'Install_Order') {
                options = [ {"label" : "All Documents with Change Request", "value" : "All_Doc_WITH_CO"}, 
                           {"label" : "All Documents without Change Request", "value" : "All_Doc_WITO_CO"}, 
                           {"label" : "Customer Completion Form", "value" : "CustCompletion"}, 
                           {"label" : "Installation Change Authorization", "value" : "InstallChangeAuth"}, 
                           {"label" : "Lead Safe Form", "value" : "LeadSafe"},
                           {"label" : "Lien Waiver", "value" : "InstLienWaiver"}, 
                           {"label" : "Moisture Reading", "value" : "MoistureReading"}, 
                           {"label" : "Work Order", "value" : "InstWorkOrder"},
                           {"label" : "Invoice", "value" : "Invoice"},
                           {"label" : "Photos", "value" : "InstallPhotos"},
                           {"label" : "Other Files", "value" : "Other Files"}];
            } else if (recordType == 'Measure_Order') {
                options = [{"label" : "Project Assessment Form", "value" : "IPProjectAssess"},
                          {"label" : "Photos", "value" : "MeasurePhotos"},
                          {"label" : "Other Files", "value" : "Other Files"}];
            }
            component.set('v.fileOptions', options);
            help.getParentServiceRequest(component, recId)
        }))
        .catch(function(errors) {
            console.error('get record type error: ' + errors);

        });
    },
```

Comment: What have you tried? Where are you stuck? Crafting logic for requirements is not a goal of this community, but we can help you with specific problems. Please read [ask] and then make an [edit].

Answer (score 0):

Use a wrapper that has a string property that holds the Profile Id/Name.

Comment: Can you pls help with the syntax